# Why assume controls are independent of state estimation in Kalman Filter?

Tags: bayesian, estimation, kalman-filter, control-theory

Here's the classic graphical model depiction of a Kalman Filter (or any form of Bayes filter for that matter).

[image]

Why do we assume that the controls are independent of the previous state estimation? For example, if we are trying to maintain a car's cruise control at 100 km/h, then clearly the control is not independent of the state. In fact, we would often decide on our control with a PID controller for example. So in my mind, it should look somewhat like this:

[image]

Is the reason why its not simply mathematical simplification, or is there something deeper I'm not seeing?

Comment: If the control is $\{u_i\}$ then those are controlled by a person. They aren't random.

Comment: Not sure if you are agreeing with me or adding to my point? Whether the controls come from a person or from a PID is the same, they are still dependent on the previous state (for example, if you are in front of a wall, you wouldn't give a forward control).

Comment: you could. If it isn't random, it isn't random.

Comment: I know you could. I was wondering whether it makes the mathematics much more difficult in some places, which would explain why its not usually done this way.